# How to turn off verification after DVD burning on OS X?

Tags: macos, dvd, burning, disk-utility, verification

I use the built in DVD burner from OS X. Whenever I burn a disk, it is verified after burning. Nice, but I am usually quicker in verifying myself with a bit more human, maybe more error prone process... Just takes too long!

Is there a way to turn this off in OS X?

Thanks!

Comment: The verification process that DiskUtility uses is pretty darn robust, and not that slow...  What do you propose to use instead of it?  Even these days a failure will occasionally happen during burning...  It's saved me quite a few times...

Comment: I agree, despite answering below. The time to find out the disc is bad is right away, not when you need it down the road.

Comment: I also agree with the previous comments. But if you are bound and determined to shoot yourself in the foot, then you should edit your post to specify which version of OS X you are using and provide more detail about how you are burning the disc. Otherwise folks have to guess when they try to answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a disc to verify that this is it, but it looks like this preference got moved into Disk Utility's prefs. Open Terminal and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DRBurnOptionsVerifyBurn -bool NO
```

To go back to the default replace NO with YES.

Edit: Fixed spelling of [disc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2300).

Comment: Not working as of 2022